# Conversion of class file to Java files

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, war, decompiling, .class-file

I have one War files (a Java application) consist of 64 class file along with image/CSS/JS files. I have lost the source of this war file. Now I want to do some changes in code. I am looking for some expert advice from community on following questions.

1. Is there best way to convert .class files to .java file without losing any section of code?
2. What are the tools if any for this task?
3. What are challenges/drawbacks of converting .class files to .java files to recreate war file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to spend horrible times in understanding decompiled bytecode, **please start using a version control system and a remote repository for any project of more than two classes.**

In particular, you can use Git with GitHub, open source are hosted for free while if you want to protect your code you can get a commercial subscription which is cheap anyway.

For this time, help yourself with a java decompiler such as JD:

1. Use a java decompiler to decompile the bytecode.
2. Create a git repository out of the decompiled java classes
3. Constantly synchronize it with the remote repository

Comment: JD s very good. There is even an Eclipse plugin. Drawbacks, in general, are: * You lose all comments.
* Depending on debug info in the class file, you lose line numbers.
* You might lose the names of local variables.
* Sometimes the resulting Java code might not compile. Decompilers might fail with comples constructs. Inner classes come to mind. It's easily fixed by hand, though.

Answer (score 3):

1. Conversion to Java Bytecode is almost completely reversible. As @StephenC said, In the regenerated sources, you will lose comments, names of local variables etc. It might not compile right away but you should be able to get it to compile again, with a little modification.
2. You need a Java Decompiler to do that. Try [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) or [DJ Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/dj.html)
3. In case you obfuscated your sources, the sources you recover will not be harder to understand and reverse engineer. Otherwise, with just a little tinkering, you should be able to get back your sources.

Comment: *"In most cases, conversion to Java Bytecode is almost completely reversible."* - this is patently FALSE.  Comments, local variable names & compile time constant expressions cannot be recovered.  Indeed, in a lot of cases a typical Java decompiler cannot even produce compilable Java code ... let alone code that resembles the original code.

Comment: I was speaking from experience. And `local variable names` and `defined constants` being non-recoverable is true, but that doesn't affect the "compilability" of regenerated sources

Comment: Please edit my answer, if you think my statement is inaccurate.

Comment: @StephenC really?  JD does a bag up job in my experience, unless the code has been obfuscated

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I cannot speak for that particular tool.  But for others, obfuscated code and code generated by the latest Oracle Java compilers can be problematic.  (And code generated by non-Oracle compilers ...).  My complaint was (in part) about the "in most cases" optimism ... which is IMO unwarranted.

Comment: @StephenC look, fair point, any reverse engineering process isn't going to be perfect, but if you've got nothing left, this helps a lot (had experience where the senior developer for a database interface died, leaving the source code in disarray.  It's taken us nearly two years just to figure out what's in production - don't ask.  But we had to decompile the production code just to be sure).  Any tool of this nature should be, as you have rightfully pointed out, be treated carefully and should never replace good version control practices.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I hope that programmer's MANAGER was shown the door, because it is a major failure of IT management to allow a system to get into such a precarious state.

Comment: @StephenC That would be the owner of the business and I agree